# Помогите с парсингом

Tags: python, парсер, web-scraping

Как спарсить отсюда значения(count, average, min, max)?

Код:

<media:starRating count="605" average="5.00" min="1" max="5"/>

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
str = '<media:starRating count="605" average="5.00" min="1" max="5"/>'
search = re.findall(r'(count||average||min||max)=\"(.*?)\"', str)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).